# Cannot print confusion matrix for model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, mnist, confusion-matrix

I implemented an `MLP` and it works perfectly. However, I'm having an issue trying to print the confusion matrix.

My model is defined as...

```
logits = layers(X, weights, biases)
```

Where...

```
def layers(x, weights, biases):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']

    return out_layer
```

I train the model on the `mnist` dataset. After training I am am able to print out the accuracy of the model successfully...

```
pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
print("Accuracy: ", accuracy.eval({X:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))
```

The accuracy gives me 90%. Now I want to print out the confusion matrix of the results. I tried the following...

```
confusion = tf.confusion_matrix(
         labels=mnist.test.labels, predictions=correct_prediction)
```

But this gives me errors...

> ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 10 for 'confusion_matrix/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [10000,10].

What is the proper way to print out the confusion matrix? I've been struggling for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like one of the arguments for [`tf.confusion_matrix`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/confusion_matrix) has a 10 as second dim. The question is if `mnist.test.labels` or `correct_prediction` are one-hot encoded? That would explain it. You need the labels there as one dim tensors. Can you print the shapes for those two tensors?

Also it looks like `correct_prediction` is a boolean tensor to flag whether your predictions are accurate. For the confusion matrix you want the predicted label, that would be `tf.argmax( pred, 1 )` instead. Similarly, if your labels are one-hot encoded, you want to decode them for the confusion matrix. So try this line for `confusion`:

```
confusion = tf.confusion_matrix(
     labels = tf.argmax( mnist.test.labels, 1 ),
     predictions = tf.argmax( pred, 1 ) )
```

In order to print the confusion matrix itself, it is necessary to use `eval` with the final result:

```
print(confusion.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting the shapes. I used `tf.get_shape()`. For `correct_prediction` I got `Tensor("Shape_3:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32)` and for the labels I got `Tensor("Shape_4:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)`

Comment: Updated my answer. How many labels are you trying to predict? 10 or 2?

Comment: I would say 10, since there are 10 classifications

Comment: I'm still getting the same error... `ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 10 for 'confusion_matrix/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [10000,10].`

Comment: Is it not possible to create a confusion matrix for 10 classifications? If it is not easy to do, can you show me how I can do it for 1 classification at least? That would be very helpful.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to do that. I just don't know how your values are stored, I'm shooting in the dark. Are your labels one-hot encoded? So instead of, say class `5` you have [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] in labels? If yes, it should be converted to `5`. Then you can create the matrix. I'll update my answer more, give me a sec.

Comment: Yes, they are one hot encoded, just like your example.

Comment: Thank you Peter once again, I'm gonna add one part to your answer for future reference.

Comment: Sure, happy to help; also no objections to your addition. :)

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
confusion = tf.confusion_matrix(
       labels = tf.argmax( mnist.test.labels, 1 ),
       predictions = tf.argmax( y, 1 ) )
   print(confusion.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y_:mnist.test.labels})) 

[[ 960    0    2    2    1    5    7    2    1    0]
 [   0 1113    3    2    0    1    4    2   10    0]
 [   6    7  941   15   12    2   10    8   27    4]
 [   2    1   27  926    1   12    1    8   24    8]
 [   1    2    6    1  928    0    9    2    9   24]
 [   9    2    8   51   12  729   15    9   50    7]
 [  13    3   10    2    9    9  905    2    5    0]
 [   1    9   28    8   11    1    0  938    3   29]
 [   6   10    7   19    9   13    8    5  891    6]
 [   9    7    2    9   43    5    0   14   12  908]]
```

Comment: so the prediction is y and the real is y_

Answer (score 1):

For NLTK Confusion Matrix you need a list

```
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
refsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
testsets = collections.defaultdict(set)

lsum = []
tsum = []

for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(testfeats):
  refsets[label].add(i)
  observed = classifier.classify(feats)
  testsets[observed].add(i)
  lsum.append(label)
  tsum.append(observed

print (nltk.ConfusionMatrix(lsum,tsum))
```